# How to do nothing forever in an elegant way?

Tags: bash, shell-script, stdout, background-process, stdin

I have a program which produces useful information on `stdout` but also reads from `stdin`. I want to redirect its standard output to a file without providing anything on standard input. So far, so good: I can do:

```
program > output
```

and don't do anything in the tty.

However, the problem is I want to do this in the background. If I do:

```
program > output &
```

the program will get suspended ("suspended (tty input)").

If I do:

```
program < /dev/null > output &
```

the program terminates immediately because it reaches EOF.

It seems that what I need is to pipe into `program` something which does not do anything for an indefinite amount of time and does not read `stdin`. The following approaches work:

```
while true; do sleep 100; done | program > output &
mkfifo fifo && cat fifo | program > output &
tail -f /dev/null | program > output &
```

However, this is all very ugly. There *has* to be an elegant way, using standard Unix utilities, to "do nothing, indefinitely" (to paraphrase `man true`). How could I achieve this? (My main criteria for elegance here: no temporary files; no busy-waiting or periodic wakeups; no exotic utilities; as short as possible.)

Comment: Try `su -c 'program | output &' user`.  I am about to ask a similar question with creating background jobs as an acceptable method for handling a "service/daemon."  I also noticed that I could not redirect `STDERR` without also redirecting `STDOUT`.  The solution where programA sends `STDOUT` to `STDIN` of programB, then redirects `STDERR` to a log file: `programA 2> /var/log/programA.log | programB 2> /var/log/programB.log 1> /dev/null`

Comment: maybe... `su -c 'while true; do true; done | cat > ~/output &' user`?

Comment: what kind of program is that?

Comment: João Portela: This is a program I wrote, https://gitorious.org/irctk

Comment: Why not simply add a switch to that program you wrote? Also, I assume that if you close stdin with `1<&-` it will exit your program?

Comment: w00t: Did you mean "<&-"? Indeed, it makes the program terminate. Adding a switch is not a very elegant solution, because it feels like there should be a sensible way to reach the desired behavior by giving the adequate input to the program.

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935183/bash-infinite-sleep-infinite-blocking

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In shells that support them (ksh, zsh, bash4), you can start `program` as a [co-process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86372/22565).

- `ksh`: `program > output |&`
- `zsh`, `bash`: `coproc program > output`

That starts `program` in background with its input redirected from a `pipe`. The other end of the pipe is open to the shell.

Three benefits of that approach

- no extra process
- you can exit the script when `program` dies (use `wait` to wait for it)
- `program` will terminate (get `eof` on its stdin if the shell exits).

Comment: That seems to work and looks like a great idea! (To be fair, I had asked for something to pipe to my command, not for a shell feature, but this was just the XY problem at play.) I'm considering accepting this answer instead of @P.T.'s one.

Comment: @a3nm, `tail -f /dev/null` is not ideal as it does a read every second on `/dev/null` (current versions of GNU tail on Linux using inotify there is actually [a bug](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=21265)). `sleep inf` or its more portable equivalent `sleep 2147483647` are better approaches for a command that sits there doing nothing IMO (note that `sleep` is built in a few shells like `ksh93` or `mksh`).

Comment: `coproc` doesn't seem to be part of Mac OS X, while `tail -f /dev/null` works on Linux and Mac OS X. My version is `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin20)`. Obviously S.O. has an answer for this too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40181521/how-to-use-coproc-on-mac-os-x-11

Comment: Is an "elegant approach" that isn't available to most user shells, by installed base, actually elegant? Scenarios that require blocking execution, like synchronizing between concurrent/parallel threads of execution, should prioritize portability over anything else - this answer is going to fubar junior/inexperienced operators

Answer (score 103):

I don't think you're going to get any more elegant than the

```
tail -f /dev/null
```

that you already suggested (assuming this uses inotify internally, there should be no polling or wakeups, so other than being odd looking, it should be sufficient).

You need a utility that will run indefinitely, will keep its stdout open, but won't actually write anything to stdout, and won't exit when its stdin is closed. Something like `yes` actually writes to stdout.  `cat` will exit when its stdin is closed (or whatever you re-direct into it is done).  I think `sleep 1000000000d` might work, but the `tail` is clearly better.  My Debian box has a `tailf` that shortens command slightly.

Taking a different tack, how about running the program under `screen`?

Comment: I like the `tail -f /dev/null` approach the best and find it elegant enough as well, since the command usage matches the intended purpose quite closely.

Comment: From `strace tail -f /dev/null` it seems that `tail` uses `inotify` and that wakeups occur in silly cases like `sudo touch /dev/null`. It's sad that there seems to be no better solution... I wonder which would be the right syscall to use to implement a better solution.

Comment: @a3nm The syscall would be `pause`, but it isn't exposed directly to a shell interface.

Comment: P.T.: I know about `screen`, but this is to run multiple occurrences of the program from a shell script for testing purposes, so using `screen` is a bit overkill.

Comment: I don't know why this answer is so popular.  It is not as good as Waelj's by any measure except a few chars shorter.  Its more resource intensive and its not clear how it works in the absence of inotify, which is non-standard.

Comment: @sillyMunky Silly Monkey, WaelJ's answer is wrong (sends infinite zeros to stdin).

Comment: Warning: I tried putting this into a shell script on FreeBSD.  Sending SIGINT to the script fails to interrupt since `tail` keeps running, and sending SIGTERM (or SIGKILL) terminates (or kills) the shell script but `tail` keeps running in the background.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935183/bash-infinite-sleep-infinite-blocking/41655546#41655546 is worth a read for why to prefer sleep loop over tailing /dev/null

Answer (score 66):

`sleep infinity` is the clearest solution I know of.

You can use `infinity` because `sleep` accepts a floating point number*****, which may be **decimal**, **hexadecimal**, **infinity**, or **NaN**, according to `man strtod`.

* This isn't part of the POSIX standard, so isn't as portable as `tail -f /dev/null`. However, it is supported in GNU coreutils (Linux) and BSD (used on Mac) (apparently not supported on newer versions of Mac — see comments).

Comment: Haha, that's really a nice approach. :)

Comment: @a3nm: Thanks : )  Seems `sleep infinity` also [works on BSD and Mac](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sleep(1)).

Comment: What kind of resources does a infinitely sleeping process take? Just RAM?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: Yes, and a negligible amount of CPU. I don't know much about how kernels deal with processes, but certain operations may take longer, e.g. counting the number of current processes. There are very few circumstances where this would actually affect you, though.

Comment: `sleep infinity` doesn't work for me on Mac OS X 10.9. It just returns after a few microseconds.

Comment: @QuinnComendant: Really? Does it give you an error message? Does it behave differently to, e.g. `sleep some-random-text`?

Comment: `sleep infinity` and `sleep asdfasdf` both return immediately, with an exit code of  0, and no message.

Comment: Hmm, odd. I'm not sure why that's happening.

Comment: any ideas about why sleep infinity returns?  I'm on OS X 10.10.5 and have the same thing happening, just using sleep SUPER_BIG# for now. I liked the elegance of the infinity.

Comment: @yvanscher: I'm afraid I don't have a Mac to test it, but I guess Macs don't have true IEEE floating point support for console commands. Does `sleep 1e99` work for you? (thats 10^91 years)

Comment: @Zaz: I did something of the like.  I can rest easy knowing my script won't exit until the end of the life of this universe.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Doesn't work on FreeBSD 11 either nor with the sleep builtin of mksh. Works on Solaris 11 or with the ksh93 sleep builtin.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41655546/263061) claims that `sleep infinity` waits for 24 days at max; who's right?

Comment: @nh2: Excellent comment! Try `strace sleep infinity` or `strace sleep 9999999999`, you'll see that the last system call is `nanosleep({2073600, 999999999}`, so the **sleep** utility is **limited to 24 days** = 2073600 seconds, no matter what you do.

Comment: @Zaz I have investigated the issue in detail now. It turns out that you were initially correct! The `sleep` utility is **not limited to 24 days**; it is just the _first_ syscall that sleeps for 24 days, and afterwards it will do more such syscalls. See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935183/bash-infinite-sleep-infinite-blocking/41655546#comment82451583_41655546

Answer (score 23):

```sh
sleep 2147483647 | program > output &
```

Yes, `2^31-1` is a finite number, and it won't run *forever*, but I'll give you $1000 when the sleep finally times out. (Hint: one of us will be dead by then.)

- no temporary files; check.
- no busy-waiting or periodic wakeups; check
- no exotic utilities; check.
- as short as possible. Okay, it could be shorter.

Comment: bash: sleep $((64#1_____)) | program > output &

Comment: That sleeps for 68 *years*, this sleeps for 98 *centuries*: `sleep 2147483647d`...

Answer (score 12):

You can create a binary that does just that with:

```
$ echo 'main(){pause();}'| gcc -Wno-all -xc - -o pause
```

I find this elegant because the `pause` system call is literally the one system call whose sole purpose is to do nothing forever (or until a signal kills the process) without busy-waiting, doing it as a side-effect of something else or without telling the parent process (parents can elegantly nonblockingly `waitpid` on their children to be signal-stopped, and  many (most notably shells) do, while it is quite a bit harder to wait on a child to get blocked in a non-signal-raising system call).

Comment: @roaima Yup, or  `echo 'main(){pause();}'| gcc -Wno-all -xc - -o pause` on any POSIX shell.

Comment: Oops, yes of course :-) That was me overthinking it

Answer (score 8):

Here's another suggestion *using standard Unix utilities, to "do nothing, indefinitely"*.

```
sh -c 'kill -STOP $$' | program > output
```

This fires up a shell that is immediately sent `SIGSTOP`, which suspends the process. This is used as "input" to your program. The complement of `SIGSTOP` is `SIGCONT`, i.e. if you know the shell has PID 12345 you can `kill -CONT 12345` to make it continue.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can do:

```
read x < /dev/fd/1 | program > output
```

On Linux, opening /dev/fd/x where x is a file descriptor to the writing end of a pipe, gets you the reading end of the pipe, so here the same as on the stdin of program. So basically, `read` will never return, because the only thing that may write to that pipe is itself, and `read` doesn't output anything.

It will also work on FreeBSD or Solaris, but for another reason. There, opening /dev/fd/1 gets you the same resource as open on fd 1 as you'd expect and as most systems except Linux do, so the writing end of the pipe. However, on FreeBSD and Solaris, pipes are bidirectional. So as long as `program` doesn't write to its stdin (no application does), `read` will get nothing to read from that direction of the pipe.

On systems where pipes are not bidirectional, `read` will probably fail with an error when attempting to read from a write-only file descriptor. Also note that not all systems have `/dev/fd/x`.

Comment: Very nice! In fact my tests you don't need the `x` with bash; further with zsh you can just do `read` and it works (though I don't understand why!). Is this trick Linux-specific, or does it work on all *nix systems?

Comment: @a3nm, if you do `read` alone, it will read from stdin. So if it's the terminal, it will read what you type until you press enter.

Comment: sure, I understand what read does. What I don't understand is why reading from the terminal with read in a backgrounded process is blocking with bash but not with zsh.

Comment: @a3nm, I'm not sure what you mean. What do you mean by _you can just do `read` and it works_?

Comment: I'm saying that with zsh you can just do `read | program > output` and it works in the same way as what you suggested. (And I don't get why.)

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with the solutions already mentioned:

- `sleep infinity` is not supported by some libc/musl versions.
- `tail -f /dev/null` wakes up each time some process drops something to /dev/null.
- `pause()` requires `gcc` to be installed
- piping from a halted shell will keep going even after the program is terminated

A good alternative that avoids these limitations is waiting on a halted process:

`mkfifo pipe; (while :; do :; done & kill -STOP $!) > pipe; command < pipe > output & wait $!`

Answer (score 0):

Stéphane Chazelas' `read` [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222609) works on Mac OS X as well if a reading fd gets opened on `/dev/fd/1`.

```
# using bash on Mac OS X
# -bash: /dev/fd/1: Permission denied
read x </dev/fd/1 | cat >/dev/null
echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}   #  1 0

exec 3<&- 3</dev/fd/1
read x 0<&3 | cat >/dev/null
echo ${PIPESTATUS[*]}   #  0 0
```

To be able to kill `tail -f /dev/null` in a script (with SIGINT, for example) it is necessary to background the `tail` command and `wait`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# ctrl-c will kill tail and exit script
trap 'trap - INT; kill "$!"; exit' INT
exec tail -f /dev/null & wait $!
```

Comment: This workaround for macOS (using fd 3) doesn't actually work -- it reads from the shell's original stdin, so it will exit if you type something (which is what this question is trying to avoid).

Answer (score -1):

When reading these answers you have to ask yourself:

- **Is the CPU idling while your no-op command executes?** You don't want a solution which burns CPU cycles while doing your no-op command. Most answers on this page does not answer this question.
- **Is the no-op command immediately interruptible?**  This is quite often a requirement although you may not think of it up front. (the word immediately is important here: you don't want to wait for some sleep interval to expire before the process realizes it has been interrupted). Most answers on this page does not answer this question.

DO NOT IMPLEMENT ANY ANSWERS FROM THIS PAGE UNLESS YOU KNOW (AND CAN ACCEPT) HOW THE PROPOSED SOLUTION COMPLIES WITH ABOVE.

In modern Bash you can do something like `trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait` which complies with both of the above requirements. However, it seems convoluted and brittle to me. It won't work on Linux/FreeBSD/MacOS implementations which do not support `sleep infinity`. This being said, it is probably the best userland solution at the moment.

The requirement is dead simple to implement in C. The Kubernetes project has done it in their famous `pause` docker image which is one of the smallest docker images known to man. You can find the C source code [HERE](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4abf29c5c86349c7d2c769d267f4552ced5d0c15/build/pause/linux/pause.c) (it can be shortened even further). Unfortunately, I do not know of a userland "pause" command in Linux, at least not one which has been accepted into the major distros.

Comment: Most if not all of your concerns are already addressed in other answers here. None of the current answers suggest busy loops. All are interruptible in some way or another. At least one of the existing answers already provides an implementation of `pause`. Even your suggested implementation of `sleep infinity` is over-complex as `sleep` itself is already interruptible

Answer (score -4):

Redirect `/dev/zero` as standard input!

```
program < /dev/zero > output &
```

Comment: This would give his program an infinite number of zero-bytes... which, sadly, would make it busy-loop.

Comment: This is not true jander, /dev/zero will never close, holding the pipe chain open.  However, poster says he doesn't take in stdin, so no zeros will ever be transferred to program.  This is not a busy loop at all, it is a pure wait.

Comment: sorry, OP does use stdin, so this will wipe out his input and will be drawing from /dev/zero.  I should read twice next time!

If OP wasn't using stdin, this would be the most elegant solution I've seen, and would not be a busy wait.