# How do you use the command coproc in various shells?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, ksh, coprocesses

Can someone provide a couple of examples on how to use [`coproc`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc)?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

co-processes are a `ksh` feature (already in `ksh88`). `zsh` has had the feature from the start (early 90s), while it has just only been added to `bash` in `4.0` (2009).

However, the behaviour and interface is significantly different between the 3 shells.

The idea is the same, though: it allows to start a job in background and being able to send it input and read its output without having to resort to  named pipes.

That is done with unnamed pipes with most shells and socketpairs with recent versions of ksh93 on some systems.

In `a | cmd | b`, `a` feeds data to `cmd` and `b` reads its output. Running `cmd` as a co-process allows the shell to be both `a` and `b`.

### ksh co-processes

In `ksh`, you start a coprocess as:

```bash
cmd |&
```

You feed data to `cmd` by doing things like:

```bash
echo test >&p
```

or

```bash
print -p test
```

And read `cmd`'s output with things like:

```bash
read var <&p
```

or

```bash
read -p var
```

`cmd` is started as any background job, You can use `fg`, `bg`, `kill` on it and refer it by `%job-number` or via `$!`.

To close the writing end of the pipe `cmd` is reading from, you can do:

```bash
exec 3>&p 3>&-
```

And to close the reading end of the other pipe (the one `cmd` is writing to):

```bash
exec 3<&p 3<&-
```

You cannot start a second co-process unless you first save the pipe file descriptors to some other fds. For instance:

```bash
tr a b |&
exec 3>&p 4<&p
tr b c |&
echo aaa >&3
echo bbb >&p
```

### zsh co-processes

In `zsh`, co-processes are nearly identical to those in `ksh`. The only real difference is that `zsh` co-processes are started with the `coproc` keyword.

```bash
coproc cmd
echo test >&p
read var <&p
print -p test
read -p var
```

Doing:

```bash
exec 3>&p
```

Note: This doesn't move the `coproc` file descriptor to fd `3` (like in `ksh`), but duplicates it. So, there's no explicit way to close the feeding or reading pipe, other starting *another* `coproc`.

For instance, to close the feeding end:

```bash
coproc tr a b
echo aaaa >&p # send some data

exec 4<&p     # preserve the reading end on fd 4
coproc :      # start a new short-lived coproc (runs the null command)

cat <&4       # read the output of the first coproc
```

In addition to pipe based co-processes, `zsh` (since 3.1.6-dev19, released in 2000) has pseudo-tty based constructs like `expect`. To interact with most programs, ksh-style co-processes won't work, since programs start buffering when their output is a pipe.

Here are some examples.

**Start the co-process `x`:**

```bash
zmodload zsh/zpty
zpty x cmd
```

(Here, `cmd` is a simple command. But you can do fancier things with `eval` or functions.)

**Feed a co-process data:**

```bash
zpty -w x some data
```

**Read co-process data (in the simplest case):**

```bash
zpty -r x var
```

Like `expect`, it can wait for some output from the co-process matching a given pattern.

### bash co-processes

The bash syntax is a lot newer, and builds on top of a new feature recently added to ksh93, bash, and zsh that provides a syntax to allow handling of dynamically-allocated file descriptors above 10.

`bash` offers a **basic** `coproc` syntax, and an **extended** one.

#### Basic syntax

**The basic syntax for starting a co-process looks like `zsh`'s:**

```bash
coproc cmd
```

In `ksh` or `zsh`, the pipes to and from the co-process are accessed with `>&p` and `<&p`.

But in `bash`, the file descriptors of the pipe from the co-process and the other pipe to the co-proccess are returned in the `$COPROC` array (respectively `${COPROC[0]}` and `${COPROC[1]}`. So…

**Feed data to the co-process:**

```bash
echo xxx >&"${COPROC[1]}"
```

**Read data from the co-process:**

```bash
read var <&"${COPROC[0]}"
```

With the basic syntax, you can start only one co-process at the time.

#### Extended syntax

In the extended syntax, you can *name* your co-processes (like in `zsh` zpty co-proccesses):

```bash
coproc mycoproc { cmd; }
```

The command *has* to be a compound command. (Notice how the example above is reminiscent of `function f { ...; }`.)

This time, the file descriptors are in `${mycoproc[0]}` and `${mycoproc[1]}`.

You can start more than one co-process at a time—but you *do* get a warning when you start a co-process while one is still running (even in non-interactive mode).

You can close the file descriptors when using the extended syntax.

```bash
coproc tr { tr a b; }
echo aaa >&"${tr[1]}"

exec {tr[1]}>&-

cat <&"${tr[0]}"
```

Note that closing that way doesn't work in bash versions prior to 4.3 where you have to write it instead:

```bash
fd=${tr[1]}
exec {fd}>&-
```

As in `ksh` and `zsh`, those pipe file descriptors are marked as close-on-exec.

But in `bash`, the only way to pass those to executed commands is to duplicate them to fds `0`, `1`, or `2`. That limits the number of co-processes you can interact with for a single command. (See below for an example.)

### yash process and pipeline redirection

[`yash`](http://yash.osdn.jp/doc/) doesn't have a co-process feature per se, but the same concept can be implemented with its *pipeline* and *process* redirection features. `yash` has an interface to the `pipe()` system call, so this kind of thing can be done relatively easily by hand there.

You'd start a co-process with:

```bash
exec 5>>|4 3>(cmd >&5 4<&- 5>&-) 5>&-
```

Which first creates a `pipe(4,5)` (5 the writing end, 4 the reading end), then redirects fd 3 to a pipe to a process that runs with its stdin at the other end, and stdout going to the pipe created earlier. Then we close the writing end of that pipe in the parent which we won't need. So now in the shell we have fd 3 connected to the cmd's stdin and fd 4 connected to cmd's stdout with pipes.

Note that the close-on-exec flag is not set on those file descriptors.

To feed data:

```bash
echo data >&3 4<&-
```

To read data:

```bash
read var <&4 3>&-
```

And you can close fds as usual:

```bash
exec 3>&- 4<&-
```

---

### Now, why they are not so popular

#### hardly any benefit over using named pipes

Co-processes can easily be implemented with standard named pipes. I don't know when exactly named pipes were introduced but it's possible it was after `ksh` came up with co-processes (probably in the mid 80s, ksh88 was "released" in 88, but I believe `ksh` was used internally at AT&T a few years before that) which would explain why.

```bash
cmd |&
echo data >&p
read var <&p
```

Can be written with:

```bash
mkfifo in out

cmd <in >out &
exec 3> in 4< out
echo data >&3
read var <&4
```

Interacting with those is more straightforward—especially if you need to run more than one co-process. (See examples below.)

The only benefit of using `coproc` is that you don't have to clean up of those named pipes after use.

#### deadlock-prone

Shells use pipes in a few constructs:

- **shell pipes:** `cmd1 | cmd2`,
- **command substitution:** `$(cmd)`,
- and **process substitution:** `<(cmd)`, `>(cmd)`.

In those, the data flows in **only one** direction between different processes.

With co-processes and named pipes, though, it's easy to run into deadlock. You have to keep track of which command has which file descriptor open, to prevent one staying open and holding a process alive. Deadlocks can be tricky to investigate, because they may occur non-deterministically; for instance, only when as much data as to fill one pipe up is sent.

#### works worse than `expect` for what it's been designed for

The main purpose of co-processes was to provide the shell with a way to interact with commands. However, it does not work so well.

The simplest form of deadlock mentioned above is:

```bash
tr a b |&
echo a >&p
read var<&p
```

Because its output doesn't go to a terminal, `tr` buffers its output. So it won't output anything until either it sees end-of-file on its `stdin`, or it has accumulated a buffer-full of data to output. So above, after the shell has output  `a\n` (only 2 bytes), the `read` will block indefinitely because `tr` is waiting for the shell to send it more data.

In short, pipes aren't good for interacting with commands. Co-processes can only be used to interact with commands that don't buffer their output, *or* commands which can be told not to buffer their output; for example, by using `stdbuf` with some commands on recent GNU or FreeBSD systems.

That's why `expect` or `zpty` use pseudo-terminals instead. `expect` is a tool designed for interacting with commands, and it does it well.

#### File descriptor handling is fiddly, and hard to get right

Co-processes can be used to do some more complex plumbing than what simple shell pipes allow.

[that other Unix.SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66875/22565) has an example of a coproc usage.

**Here's a simplified example:** Imagine you want a function that feeds a copy of a command's output to 3 other commands, and then have the output of those 3 commands get concatenated.

All using pipes.

For instance: feed the output of `printf '%s\n' foo bar` to `tr a b`, `sed 's/./&&/g'`, and `cut -b2-` to obtain something like:

```bash
foo
bbr
ffoooo
bbaarr
oo
ar
```

First, it's not necessarily obvious, but there’s a possibility for deadlock there, and it will start to happen after only a few kilobytes of data.

Then, depending on your shell, you’ll run in a number of different problems that have to be addressed differently.

For instance, with `zsh`, you'd do it with:

```bash
f() (
  coproc tr a b
  exec {o1}<&p {i1}>&p
  coproc sed 's/./&&/g' {i1}>&- {o1}<&-
  exec {o2}<&p {i2}>&p
  coproc cut -c2- {i1}>&- {o1}<&- {i2}>&- {o2}<&-
  tee /dev/fd/$i1 /dev/fd/$i2 >&p {o1}<&- {o2}<&- &
  exec cat /dev/fd/$o1 /dev/fd/$o2 - <&p {i1}>&- {i2}>&-
)
printf '%s\n' foo bar | f
```

Above, the co-process fds have the close-on-exec flag set, but *not* the ones that are duplicated from them (as in `{o1}<&p`). So, to avoid deadlocks, you’ll have to make sure they're closed in any processes that don't need them.

Similarly, we have to use a subshell and use `exec cat` in the end, to ensure there's no shell process lying about holding a pipe open.

With `ksh` (here `ksh93`), that would have to be:

```bash
f() (
  tr a b |&
  exec {o1}<&p {i1}>&p
  sed 's/./&&/g' |&
  exec {o2}<&p {i2}>&p
  cut -c2- |&
  exec {o3}<&p {i3}>&p
  eval 'tee "/dev/fd/$i1" "/dev/fd/$i2"' >&"$i3" {i1}>&"$i1" {i2}>&"$i2" &
  eval 'exec cat "/dev/fd/$o1" "/dev/fd/$o2" -' <&"$o3" {o1}<&"$o1" {o2}<&"$o2"
)
printf '%s\n' foo bar | f
```

(**Note:** That won’t work on systems where `ksh` uses `socketpairs` instead of `pipes`, and where `/dev/fd/n` works like on Linux.)

In `ksh`, fds above `2` are marked with the close-on-exec flag, unless they’re passed explicitly on the command line. That’s why we don't have to close the unused file descriptors like with `zsh`—but it’s also why we have to do `{i1}>&$i1` and use `eval` for that new value of `$i1`, to be passed to `tee` and `cat`…

In `bash` this cannot be done, because you can't avoid the close-on-exec flag.

Above, it's relatively simple, because we use only simple external commands. It gets more complicated when you want to use shell constructs in there instead, and you start running into shell bugs.

Compare the above with the same using named pipes:

```bash
f() {
  mkfifo p{i,o}{1,2,3}
  tr a b < pi1 > po1 &
  sed 's/./&&/g' < pi2 > po2 &
  cut -c2- < pi3 > po3 &

  tee pi{1,2} > pi3 &
  cat po{1,2,3}
  rm -f p{i,o}{1,2,3}
}
printf '%s\n' foo bar | f
```

### Conclusion

If you want to interact with a command, use `expect`, or `zsh`'s `zpty`, or named pipes.

If you want to do some fancy plumbing with pipes, use named pipes.

Co-processes can do some of the above, but be prepared to do some serious head scratching for anything non-trivial.

Comment: Great answer indeed. I don't know when specifically it was fixed, but as of at least `bash 4.3.11`, you _can_ now close coproc file descriptors directly, without the need for an aux. variable; in terms of the example in your answer `exec {tr[1]}<&-`  would now work (to close the coproc's stdin; note that your code (indirectly) tries to close `{tr[1]}` using `>&-`, but `{tr[1]}` is the coproc's _stdin_, and must be closed with `<&-`). The fix must have come somewhere between `4.2.25`, which still exhibits the problem, and `4.3.11`, which doesn't.

Comment: @mklement0, thanks. `exec {tr[1]}>&-` does indeed seem to work with newer versions and is referenced in a CWRU/changelog entry (_allow words like {array[ind]} to be valid redirection..._ 2012-09-01). `exec {tr[1]}<&-` (or the more correct `>&-` equivalent though that makes no difference as that just calls `close()` for both) doesn't close the coproc's stdin, but the writing end of the pipe to that coproc.

Comment: Thanks for researching, clarifying, and thanks for updating your answer. Can I suggest that you mention the 4.3 thing not only in the code comment, but also in the text above, such as "a bit cumbersome in Bash versions before 4.3"?

Comment: @mklement0, good point, I've updated it and added `yash`.

Comment: One advantage over `mkfifo` is that you don't have to worry about race conditions and security for pipe access. You still have to worry about deadlock with fifo's.

Comment: About deadlocks: the `stdbuf` command can help to prevent at least some of them. I used it under Linux and bash. Anyway I believe @StéphaneChazelas is right in the Conclusion: the "head scratching" phase ended for me only when I switched back to named pipes.

Comment: As to why they didn't use named pipes in ksh: named pipes were introduced very early on, long before ksh (I have a unix system III running in an emulator, and it does have them), but they were adopted very late in bsd (in 44bsd), so they weren't a portable solution.

Comment: 'But in bash, the only way to pass those to executed commands is to duplicate them to fds 0, 1, or 2. That limits the number of co-processes you can interact with for a single command.'  Really? This works for me `exec 3<&${p[0]}; cat /proc/$$/fd/3` in bash 4.4.23 (for a coproc named p). Also, I don't understand: 'In bash this cannot be done, because you can't avoid the close-on-exec flag.' - I mean can't you avoid it by duplicating the file descriptor (because the close-on-exec flag isn't duplicated ...)?

Comment: Ok, regarding the 2nd part: I've straced a bash script and bash directly calls `FD_CLOEXEC` on the duplicated file descriptor with `fcntl()` after the `dup2()` call.

Comment: Truly a brilliant answer

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644764/zsh-zpty-how-to-read-the-output-of-a-process-after-it-has-exited

Comment: There should be a huge warning that tells that if the co-process exists, it will concurrently unset the variables through which you access the file descriptors and PID. So, you must ensure that the consumer controls when the co-process will exit, or else the script will "randomly" fail (depending on timing). At least on bash (4.2.46) it does this.

Comment: The most underrated answer of all time.

Answer (score 8):

Co-processes were first introduced in a shell scripting language with the `ksh88` shell (1988), and later in `zsh` at some point before 1993.

The syntax to launch a co-process under ksh is `command |&`. Starting from there, you can write to `command` standard input with `print -p` and read its standard output with `read -p`.

More than a couple of decades later, bash which was lacking this feature finally introduced it in its 4.0 release. Unfortunately, an incompatible and more complex syntax was selected.

Under bash 4.0 and newer, you can launch a co-process with the `coproc` command, eg:

```
$ coproc awk '{print $2;fflush();}'
```

You can then pass something to the command stdin that way:

```
$ echo one two three >&${COPROC[1]}
```

and read awk output with:

```
$ read -ru ${COPROC[0]} foo
$ echo $foo
two
```

Under ksh, that would have been:

```
$ awk '{print $2;fflush();}' |&
$ print -p "one two three"
$ read -p foo
$ echo $foo
two
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another good (and working) example -- a simple server written in BASH. Please note that you would need OpenBSD's `netcat`, the classic one won't work. Of course you could use inet socket instead of unix one.

`server.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SOCKET=server.sock
PIDFILE=server.pid

(
    exec </dev/null
    exec >/dev/null
    exec 2>/dev/null
    coproc SERVER {
        exec nc -l -k -U $SOCKET
    }
    echo $SERVER_PID > $PIDFILE
    {
        while read ; do
            echo "pong $REPLY"
        done
    } <&${SERVER[0]} >&${SERVER[1]}
    rm -f $PIDFILE
    rm -f $SOCKET
) &
disown $!
```

`client.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SOCKET=server.sock

coproc CLIENT {
    exec nc -U $SOCKET
}

{
    echo "$@"
    read
} <&${CLIENT[0]} >&${CLIENT[1]}

echo $REPLY
```

Usage:

```
$ ./server.sh
$ ./client.sh ping
pong ping
$ ./client.sh 12345
pong 12345
$ kill $(cat server.pid)
$
```

Answer (score 1):

**What is a "coproc"?**

It's short for "co-process" which means a second process cooperating with
the shell.  It's very similar to a background job started with an "&" at
the end of the command, except that instead of sharing the same standard
input and output as its parent shell, its standard I/O is connected to
the parent shell by a special kind of pipe called a FIFO.For reference [click here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00095.html)

One starts a coproc in zsh with:

```
coproc command
```

The command has to be prepared to read from stdin and/or write to stdout,
or it isn't of much use as a coproc.

Read this article [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-co-processes) it provides a case study between exec and coproc

Comment: Can you add some of the article to your answer? I was trying to get this topic covered in U&L since it seemed under represented. Thanks for your answer! Also notice I set the tag as Bash, not zsh.

Comment: @slm You already pointed to Bash hackers. I saw there sufficient examples. If your intension was to bring this question under attention then yes you succeeded :>

Comment: They're not special kinds of pipes, they are the same pipes as used with `|`. (that is use pipes in most shells, and socketpairs in ksh93). pipes and socketpairs are first-in, first-out, they're all FIFO. `mkfifo` makes named pipes, coprocesses don't use named pipes.

Comment: @slm sorry for zsh... actually i work on zsh. I tend to do it sometimes with the flow. It works fine in Bash too...

Comment: @ Stephane Chazelas I am pretty sure that i read it somewhere that it's I/O is connected with special kinds of  pipes called FIFO...

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin - if you can find the source add it as a reference.

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin as already stated, all pipes are FIFO by design. Otherwise they wouldn't have been called pipes in the first place.

Comment: @jilliagre as i said "i read it somewhere" and i included the reference for it... and Stephane Chazelas already mentioned that pipes are FIFO by design...thank you for stating it again.... And for future references I got the fact that pipes are FIFO.... i am including the [link](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2011/msg00095.html) again ...

Comment: @MunaiDasUdasin In Unix, _[named pipes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)_ are commonly called FIFOs, although **all** pipes are first-in-first-out by design. Named pipes differ from traditional, _unnamed pipes_ in that named pipes can persist beyond the lifetime of the process that created them, while unnamed pipes persist only for the lifetime of the process. It seems that the `zsh` implementation of coprocesses involve a named pipe `p` , but `bash` coprocesses, which the question is explicitly about, use traditional unnamed pipes.

Comment: @ThomasNyman, `zsh` or `ksh` co-processes don't use named pipes. It's `>&p`, not `>p`. The `>&p` is a special syntax that means, redirect to the co-process (using unnamed pipes). unnamed pipes can persist after the lifetime of the process (in its children, of in a process that has opened /proc/pid/fd/n on Linux for instance)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas You are of course correct, although whereas unnamed pipes are mostly used for parent-child communication, opening them through `/proc/pid/fd/` is perhaps not typical usage. A better choice of words would probably have been that named pipes persist as long as the corresponding file system object exists, or the pipe is kept open by the processes accessing it, whereas unnamed pipes have no associated file system object (apart from the file descriptor in `/proc/pid/fd/`), and persist only as long as they are kept open by processes.