# Piping output between two simultaneous, independent programs

Tags: pipe

Let's say I have two programs which play chess: `chess_1` and `chess_2`. They keep track of the board themselves, and take as input opposing moves, and then output their moves. For example, if I wanted to play against `chess_1`, I would do the following:

I would start the program (assuming I am white)

```
$ ./chess_1                  # program starts and hangs for input
  <my move>                  # my input
  <the bot's move>           # bot output
  <my next move>             # my input
.... < etc. > .....
```

And the bot would keep track of the game board. My question is, how can I make `chess_1` play against `chess_2`?

Comment: In other words, you means tie stdout of `chess1` to stdin of `chess2` and vice versa?  For a start I would say you should be allowing the move to be specified through `stdin` rather than via a command line argument.  After that, why not just use named pipes?

Comment: @Wildcard I think so. Honestly I know that this information exists out there, but I really had no idea what it was called so I was having a hard time finding it. I'll look for "named pipes". (I also changed i/o to stdin int eh question)

Comment: They're also called `fifo`s (for "first in first out"); that may help.  The tool to create them is `mkfifo` but the man page assumes you already know what they are.  :)  Here's an [Introduction to Named Pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156).

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the shell, so, in general, named pipes would be easiest way. However, if your shell supports them, this could be a nice use case for coprocesses.

[How do you use the command coproc in Bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-bash)

> In `a | cmd | b`, `a` feeds data to `cmd` and `b` reads its output.
>   Running `cmd` as a co-process allows the shell to be both `a` and `b`.

In bash:

```
coproc ./chess_1
./chess_2 < "${COPROC[0]}" > "${COPROC[1]}"
```

The linked post also talks about drawbacks of coprocesses, and has examples of using named pipes (via `mkfifo`).