# send to log and display on console

Tags: bash, trap, logs

I have a small test script here, it has error handling. I would like all STDERR and STDOUT to be displayed on the console (which they currently are) AND made into a log file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# error handling
function error_handler() {
  echo "Error occurred in script at line: ${1}."
  echo "Line exited with status: ${2}"
}

trap 'error_handler ${LINENO} $?' ERR

set -o errexit
set -o errtrace
set -o nounset

if rsync -aPh ~/Downloads/Temps-linux-x64.zip .; then
        echo "SUCCESSFULL rsync of files"
else
        echo "FAILED rsync of files"
fi
```

I have tried to trap it by adding this to the start;

```
exec 3>&1 4>&2
trap 'exec 2>&4 1>&3' 0 1 2 3
exec 1>log.out 2>&1
```

but this (as it's supposed to) logs everything but has no output to the console. It's also causing the error handling to not work correctly so I need another solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [descriptor redirection to a coproc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-bash)

```
#!/bin/bash 
exec 3<&1
coproc mytee { tee log.out >&3;  }
exec >&${mytee[1]} 2>&1

... your script ...
```

*STDOUT and STDERR will be merged in the script output. It would be nice someone found a way to have them merged in the log file but separated in the  output.*

Answer (score 0):

Use `tee`:

```
./script 2>&1 | tee log.out
```

`tee` copies standard input to standard output and to any specified file(s); in the example above this is `log.out`. For more info, see `man tee`.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to incorporate it into the script though?

Comment: @eekfonky You can add the same command at the end of your `echo` statements.