# Capture the output of a shell function without a subshell

Tags: shell, variable, command-substitution, subshell

I have `rbenv` (ruby version manager) installed on machine and it works like that:

```
$ rbenv local
2.3.1
```

Writing to *stdout* the local version of my ruby. I want to rescue this version and declare it in a variable to reuse in another occasion.

```
$ declare -r RUBY_DEFINED_VERSION=$(rbenv local)
$ echo Using ruby version $RUBY_DEFINED_VERSION
Using ruby version 2.3.1
```

It works!

But I don't want to use a *subshell* to do the work (using `$()` or ``` `` ```). I want to use the same *shell* and I don't want to create a *tmp* file to do the work.

Is there a way to do this?

**Note:** `declare -r` is not mandatory, it can be a simple `var=FOOBAR`.

Comment: if you wanna call rbenv in current shell ; then you need at laest a named pip ; cmd > fifo; var="`<fifo`" !

Comment: Any _reason_ for not wanting to use `$(...)` or temporary file?

Comment: @Kusalananda The `rbenv local` changes some variables and I want to use these variables. The shell script will run on various projects and I can't trust in `/tmp` or permissions. Some machines I just can write on `/var/tmp`.

Comment: Can't you just parse the `.ruby-version` file in the current directory? BTW, I can not find anything that says `rbenv local` changes anything. It's supposed to only report the local version according to https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-local

Comment: @Kusalananda in case of `rvm` (the shell script will prevent the `rbenv` and `rvm`) some variables are set, like `RUBY_VERSION`. But I think I can use `cat .ruby-version`. :-)

Comment: Are any of `$TMP`, `$TMPDIR` or `$TEMP` set in your environment?  These are the environment variables that Ruby itself checks when [finding the temp folder](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/tmpdir/rdoc/Dir.html#method-c-tmpdir).

Comment: @JigglyNaga I really don't wan't to use `tmp` file. It must exist another way.

Comment: If we forget the temp files, why you don't want to use the `$( )` method? Is a temp subshell that will only be used to return to your variable the output of the command....

Comment: You can use `read variable < <(rbenv local)`  witch as far as i know works on the same shell using process substitution.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564995/how-to-modify-a-global-variable-within-a-function-in-bash

Answer (score 13):

There is a hack, but I think it just make sense if you need it in a loop.

you can open a `cat` `coproc` like this: `coproc CAT { cat; }`

This will start a `cat` command in background, and set two environment variables: `CAT_PID` and `CAT`. The `CAT` variable is an array with `STDOUT` and `STDIN` (in this order) file descriptor (pipes) used by `cat`.

So, you can execute anything writing the output to `&${CAT[1]}` that represents the `STDIN`, and use the builtin command `read` to set your variable reading from `${CAT[0]}` that is the `STDOUT` of cat.

Here a sample:

```bsh
coproc CAT { cat; }
echo 123 >&${CAT[1]}
read myvar <&${CAT[0]}
```

To test:

```bsh
echo $myvar
123
```

Don't forget to stop the cat after use it. You can do it by by killing the process.

```bsh
kill $CAT_PID
```

This makes a great difference in performance tuning.

Update: `bash` implements strings `null` delimited. So when dealing with binary data, `read` is really tricky. You can read with `LC_ALL=C read -r -n1 -d $'\0'` one byte at time, then the null will be empty strings on `${REPLY}` variable.

Comment: `IFS= read -r -d $'\0' myvar` to read null-delimited data

Comment: anyone have an idea on how to get this or something similar working in zsh?

Comment: try something like this: `coproc cat; echo test >&p ; read -p var; echo $var` ... and look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-various-shells)

Answer (score 5):

With bash you can also do it like this :

```
read a < <(echo hello)
echo "$a"
```

Or like this :

```
shopt -s lastpipe
echo hello | read a
shopt -u lastpipe
echo "$a"
```

But you still have to launch a sub-process which will run ruby, so I don't really understand what you are trying to avoid...

Comment: I really don't understand why this answer was downvoted.

Comment: what is a? is that a variable?

Comment: `read a`, where `a` in this case is a variable where the `read command` you put the content readed. The command `read` will create or replace this variable and you can put any non-reserved word here, If you do not want to choose a name, you can omit it and the default variable name is `REPLY`, so you can read the content from `$REPLY`, use `help read` for more details.

Comment: Your first method has a subshell, breaking variable assignment. So `read a < <(foo=bar; echo baz); echo "$a:$foo"` outputs `baz:` instead of `baz:bar`. Your second method doesn't change `$a`'s value. Maybe `shopt -u lastpipe` is broken for me?

Comment: Running `bash -x yourscript.sh` with your first code example makes very clear the problem. You are doing command substitution hence the command runs in a subshell. While second examples runs in the current shell so even running changing environment commands will work well. Thank you.

Comment: To avoid you headaches remember that bash builtin man pages says:
```lastpipe:
If set, and job control is not active, the shell runs the last command of a pipeline not executed in the background in the current shell  environment.```

Answer (score 5):

If on Linux, with `bash` versions prior to 5.1 (or zsh), you could do:

```
{
  chmod u+w /dev/fd/3 # only needed in bash 5.0
  rbenv local > /dev/fd/3
  IFS= read -rd '' -u 3 variable
} 3<<< ''
```

That does use a temp file like every here-document or here-string, though that's hidden to you.

`bash` 5.1 switched to using pipes instead of regular temp files (at least when the contents of the herefile/herestring is small enough to fit in a pipe buffer). With those, you can always create the temp file by hand:

```
tmpfile=$(mktemp) || exit
{
  rm -f -- "$tmpfile"
  rbenv local >&3
  IFS= read -rd '' -u4 variable
} 3> "$tmpfile" 4< "$tmpfile"
```

(deleting the tmpfile early like `<<`/`<<<` do to minimise the risk of it being left lying around if the script is killed or `rbenv` exits the shell).

If `rbenv` outputs less data than can fit in a pipe without blocking (typically 64KiB), still on Linux and Linux only, you can use a pipe instead of the temp file with:

```
{
  rbenv local > /dev/fd/3
  IFS= read -rd '' -u 3 variable
} 3< <(:)
```

With `ksh93` or recent versions of `mksh`, use the form of command substitution that doesn't start a subshell:

```
variable=${
  rbenv local
}
```

That one is also currently available in development versions of bash and zsh.

Beware that contrary to the `IFS= read -rd ''` approach, that removes the trailing newline characters in the output¹ (like in regular command substitution).

To achieve that, internally, current (as of 2024) versions of ksh93 use a pre-deleted tempfile (in `/dev/shm` on my Debian system), mksh as well (in `/tmp` on my system), zsh-dev same except the file is deleted later and bash-dev an anonymous *memfd* tempfile where supported and a pre-deleted tempfile in `/tmp` where not.

In older versions of `zsh`, you leverage the `=(...)` form of process substitution to get an automatically deleted temp file (here passed as argument to an anonymous function):

```
() { rbenv local > $1; IFS= read -rd '' variable <$1; } =()
```

---

<sup>¹ though in the case of zsh, whether to do that or not or only when `${ cmd }` is left unquoted is currently being debated.</sup>