# How to redefine bash builtin loop expression behavior?

Tags: shell

```
for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done
```

I'd like to redefine the behavior of a for loop, i.e. I want the syntax for my existing BASH scripts to remain the same while I change the meaning of the grammar.  For example, I'd like `COMMANDS` to become `coproc ( COMMANDS )` such that:

```
for i in $(seq 1 5);do sleep $[ 1 + $RANDOM % 5 ]; echo $i;done
```

**BECOMES**

```
for i in $(seq 1 5);do coproc (sleep $[ 1 + $RANDOM % 5 ]; echo $i);done
```

Comment: this would likely require editing the bash source and could break anything that is incompatible with the unexpected addition of coproc to every for loop (why do you need this... ?)

Comment: @thrig The idea was to auto-parallelize my existing scripts.  Is there a way to do it on a per-script basis?  I'd prefer to keep script statement editing to a minimum and BASH source tree modification to zero.  I'm aware of GNU parallel, but avoiding it for portability reasons.

Comment: `for` loops are routinely used in sh scripts.  Doing this would break every single one of them that wasn't expecting to run each iteration of the loop simultaneously in a background subshell (BTW, the fact that it's a subshell means it can't affect variables etc in the parent).  i.e. it's a **very** bad idea, breaking bash like this will break your system.  Use `coproc` in your scripts where you need it and don't use it where you don't.

Comment: @DerekCallaway GNU Parallel is highly portable and is supported on all newer UNICes and most older ones, too. Can you elaborate on the portability issues you have experienced with GNU Parallel? (Also have a look at --embed, which was added 20180125: It makes it possible to embed parallel in a script).

Answer (score 1):

TCL can do this [kind of thing](http://wiki.tcl.tk/685). `bash` is not TCL ;-)

See Stéphan's neat `zsh` solution also (since `zsh` has concurrent coprocs):

```
alias do='do coproc {' done='}; done'
```

It's not that it *won't* work in `bash`, but there are two problems: `bash` only properly supports a single coproc (see below); and you *should* name your coprocs when you have more than one, and `bash` currently does not apply expansion to the name (i.e. `coproc $FOO` is an error), it only accepts a static name (workaround is `eval`).

But, based on that and assuming you don't really need exactly `coproc`, what you can do is:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases         # enable aliases in a script
alias do='do (' done=')& done'  # "do ("  ... body... ")& done"
```

and this will "promote" each `do` body to a backgrounded subshell. If you need to synchronise at the bottom of the loop, a `wait` will do the trick, or to be more selective for non-trivial scripts:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
declare -a _pids
alias do='do (' done=')&  _pids+=($!); done'

for i in $(seq 1 5);do sleep $[ 1 + $RANDOM % 5 ]; echo $i;done

wait ${_pids[*]}
```

That keeps track of each new subshell in the `_pids` array.

(Using  `do { ... } &` would work too, but starts an extra shell process.)

---

**Please note** probably none of the following should ever appear in production code!

Part of what you want can be done (though inelegantly, and without great robustness), but the main problems are:

- [coprocesses](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270) are not simply for parallelization, they are designed for synchronous interaction with another process (one effect being stdin and stdout are changed to pipes, and as a subshell there can be other differences, e.g. `$$`)
- more importantly, bash (up to 4.4) only [supports a single coprocess](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc#only_one_coprocess_at_a_time) at a time.
- you can break loop control and effectively loose `break` and `exit` if the body is run in the background (but that doesn't affect the simple examples here)

You cannot get bash to do this without non-trivial modifications to its  internals (including the incomplete concurrent coprocesses implementation). Commands must be grouped explicitly with `( )` or `{ }`, this is implicit in grammar level constructions like `for/do/done`. You could pre-process your bash scripts, but this would require a parser (the current one is ~6500 lines of C/bison input) to be robust.

(The gentle reader may wish to look away now.)

You can "redefine" `do` with an alias and a function, potentially subject to lots of complications (escaping, quoting, expansion etc):

```
function _do()
{
    ( eval "$@" ) &
}
shopt -s expand_aliases    # allow alias expansion in a script
alias do="do _do"

# single command only
for i in {1..5}; do sleep $((1+$RANDOM%5)); done
```

But in order to pass multiple commands you must escape and/or quote:

```
for i in {1..5}; do "sleep $((1+$RANDOM%5)); echo $i" ; done
```

in which case you may as well dispense with the `alias` trickery and either call `_do` directly, or just amend the loops anyway.

(The gentle reader may now wish to run screaming from the building.)

Here's a slightly less error prone version using an array, but this  requires further modifications to your code:

```
function _do()
{
   local _cmd
   printf -v _cmd "%s;" "$@"
   ( eval "$_cmd" ) &
}

cmd=( 'sleep $((1+$RANDOM%5))' )
cmd+=( 'echo $i' )

for i in {1..5}; do "${cmd[@]}"  ; done
```

(I assume now the gentle reader has passed out, or is otherwise safe from further harm.)

Finally, just because it can be done, and not because it's a [good idea](http://c-faq.com/cpp/slm.html):

```
function _for() {
  local _cmd _line
  printf -v _cmd '%s ' "$@"
  printf -v _cmd "for %s\n" "$_cmd" # reconstruct "for ..."

  read _line # "do"
  _cmd+=$'do (\n'

  while read _line; do
    _cmd+="$_line"; _cmd+=$'\n'     # reconstruct loop body
  done

  _cmd+=$') &\ndone'                # finished

  unalias for                       # see note below
  eval "$_cmd"
  alias for='_for <<-"done"'
} 

shopt -s expand_aliases
alias for='_for <<-"done"'

for i in $(seq 1 5)
do
  sleep $((1+$RANDOM%5))
  echo $i
done
```

The only change required is that `do`/`done` appear alone on their own lines, and `done` must be indented with 0 or more hard tabs.

What the above does is:

- hijack `for` with an alias that calls a function with a HEREDOC that swallows the the body up to `done`.
- that function reconstructs the `for` loop from its arguments, and then by reading the rest of the body from the HEREDOC
- the reconstructed body has "( ... ) &" wedged into it, and `done` appended
- invoke `eval`, having undone the `for` alias (a `\` prefix works for aliased *commands*, but not for keywords, `unalias` and restore is required)

Again, this is not terribly robust: a redirection of the loop like `done > /dev/null` will cause problems, as will nested `for`, as will arithmetic `for (( ;; ))` which needs extra quoting to work. You cannot use the same trick to override `do`, aside from probably breaking `select/do/done` it would be simpler if it worked, but you get a syntax error (`do` with a redirect) if you attempt this.

Comment: Well, you could always do `alias do='do coproc {' done='}; done'`.

Comment: Much neater. Let me guess, it works in `zsh` ;-) Sadly the bash `coproc` is limited at this time. But I'm not certain how limited, although `MULTIPLE_COPROCS` is defined 0 at build, multiple coprocesses *do* seem to run, but it spews warnings when attempted...

Comment: Oh sorry, I hadn't thought it through. zsh does support multiple cuncurrent coprocs but not as simple as starting all of them with `coproc cmd` alone. bash does support multiple coproc to some extent with the  extended syntax. See [How do you use the command coproc in various shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270)