# zsh, zpty: How to read the output of a process after it has exited?

Tags: zsh, expect, fifo, coprocesses

Start some command with `zpty`:

```
zpty -d x ; zpty x 'echo hi' ; sleep 1
```

How do I read its output now that it has exited?

```
zpty -r x
```

Returns 2, and this behavior seems expected per the manpage.

Comment: I can't reproduce this: `zpty -d x 2>/dev/null; zpty x 'echo hi' ; sleep 1 ; zpty -r x; echo $?` →
`hi` and `0`

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Weirdly, I can't reproduce this on my Linux server (which runs the same config as my laptop) as well. Perhaps it's a macOS thing?