# Can `kill` in bash send a signal only to a single process whose process group has other process(es)?

Tags: bash, signals

Can `kill` in bash only send a signal from the current shell process to a process group? That is the impression from the posts that I have had so far.

Can `kill` in bash send a signal only to a single process whose process group has other process(es)?

In Linux, is a signal always sent from a process or the kernel to a process group, instead of to a single process?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you but you can  `kill` a `pid` or a `pgid` which to me would indicate that it can in fact send signals to individual processes.

Comment: *"In Linux, is a signal always sent from a process or the kernel to a process group, instead of to a single process?"*  FYI, this is a kernel question, not a bash question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a do nothing script (from user6915 @ [42901](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42901/how-to-do-nothing-forever-in-an-elegant-way)) in order to get a few processes running under one `pgid`:

```
[root@JBCLAMP001 ~]# ps x -o "%r %p %y %x %c"
 PGID   PID TTY          TIME COMMAND
62102 62102 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
62102 62104 pts/8    00:00:00 cat
62102 62103 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
```

Then I killed `62104` (cat):

```
 PGID   PID TTY          TIME COMMAND
62102 62102 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
62102 64207 pts/8    00:00:00 cat
62102 64206 pts/8    00:00:00 bash
```

It restarted one of the `bash` processes but I think that was just the `bash` process that `cat` was running in?  Either way it appears the parent bash process stayed open.  Am I on the right track or is this not what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks. My impression (from seeing somewhere which I can't find now) was that `kill` sends  a signal only to all the processes of a job, instead of a process in a job, or I messed up my memory with something else. A job is a process group managed by a shell. So I was thinking `kill` sends a signal only to all the processes of a process group.