# How can I fix this large email dataset?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, email

I have a very large dataset which is supposed to consist of emails. However, there are a large amount of invalid emails that need to be removed from the file completely.

Here are some examples:

```
89 is @msn .com
89!3@nomail.com
89%@yahoo.com
89%azn@yahoo.com
89&#39:s@msn.com
89&#39;Mustang@yahoo.com
89&#39;s@msn.com
89&main@yahoo.com
89+475asdjkl:jkl@aol.com
89+475asdjkl;jkl@aol.com
89+ggg@hotmail.com
```

Is there a simple approach available to remove lines which contain invalid emails from the file?

Comment: That last one definitely is not invalid. I'm not exactly sure about all the others.

Comment: Relating: https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/4957508

Comment: Fascinated to see that "[How to do nothing forever...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42901/how-to-do-nothing-forever-in-an-elegant-way)" has appeared in the Related list on the sidebar :-)

Comment: I have made many attempts, but completely failed, so thought I would ask here.

Comment: Judging by wikipedia and what I can gather from the RFC, the regex behing that link isn't even correct, since it doesn't accept local-parts that are only partially quoted...

Comment: + and & and # and % are allowed. User%internalhost@externalhost.com is pretty common.

Comment: Simple approach: send an email to each address and wait for a bounce. Bounce = invalid; no bounce = valid

Comment: @JeffSchaller as long as it's the right sort of bounce (i.e. not a _temporary_ rejection during the SMTP conversation)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As pointed out by [@Ivanivan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/204448/ivanivan), we could just use this regex in a grep instead of scripting anything:

```
grep "^[a-z0-9!#\$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\$" my_email_list.txt >> my_valid_emails.txt
```

---

A simple script can sort this for you. As commented above by [@ilkkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/170373/ilkkachu) and [@Mark Plotnick](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/49439/mark-plotnick), some of those examples are perfectly valid email addresses.

`email_validate.sh:`

```
#!/bin/bash

# email regex check
email_valid="^[a-z0-9!#\$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\$"

# set field separator to new lines
IFS=$'\n' 
# for loop checking line against regex above
for line in $(cat my_email_list.txt); do
    if [[ $line =~ $email_valid ]]; then
        echo "$line is valid"
    else
        echo "$line is invalid"
    fi
done
```

example output:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~]─[03:27 pm]
└─[$]› ./email_validate.sh
89 is @msn .com is invalid
89!3@nomail.com is valid
89%@yahoo.com is valid
89%azn@yahoo.com is valid
89&#39:s@msn.com is invalid
89&#39;Mustang@yahoo.com is invalid
89&#39;s@msn.com is invalid
89&main@yahoo.com is valid
89+475asdjkl:jkl@aol.com is invalid
89+475asdjkl;jkl@aol.com is invalid
89+ggg@hotmail.com is valid
```

if you need them deleting from the file as it runs through, just add a `sed '/$line/d'` to the if statement. Though I would personally recommend moving valid emails to a new file instead, in case you need to refer to the old

```
    if [[ $line =~ $email_valid ]]; then
        echo "$line is valid"
        echo "$line" >> my_valid_emails.txt
    else
        echo "$line is invalid - deleting"
    fi
```

Which will return something like this:

```
┌─[root@Fedora]─[~]─[03:34 pm]
└─[$]› cat my_valid_emails.txt
89!3@nomail.com
89%@yahoo.com
89%azn@yahoo.com
89&main@yahoo.com
89+ggg@hotmail.com
```

Comment: Be easier to use your regex and a `grep` statement to extract all matching lines and redirect output to a new file.  `grep ^[a-z0-9!#\$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_\`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\$ filename >> valid_emails`

Comment: ha! good point! I'm always over-complicating things.. will edit and credit :)

Comment: I think the local part can include “ double quoted strings “ to avoid problems with odd characters.. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5322#section-3.4.1

Comment: I definitely think this is over-complicated, and incorrect in some cases. The general way to iterate through lines is `while IFS= read -r line`. Using `for` [isn't recommended](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) (and there's also a useless `cat` in your code). In any case, given that the question just asks to delete the lines, there's no reason to nest the `sed` in the `if`. Just use plain `sed` (or `grep -v`).